# Remove Hyphen (-) From Text in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I remove the hyphen (-) from paragraphs of text in Photoshop. It happens when a word is split between two lines.

Comment: that's called a hyphen

Answer (score 8):

Turn off hyphenation in the Paragraph properties palette. See the image below. Remove the check mark you see there.

[image]

Comment: Didn't even remember this was a thing! Had it disabled from day 1. Learn something new every day.

Comment: You are welcome @Matt. If an answer solves your problem, you may mark it as accepted answer which is visible only to you.

Comment: Brownie points to whomever can change the default state to unchecked. I am sick of constantly turning hyphenation off.

Answer (score 2):

This is a 4 year old post, but I know lots of people still look it up - only to find instructions on how to open the "Paragraph" palette and uncheck the box. We know that already! Like user57563 said, we want to turn it off by default.

There is no setting like that - hyphenation seems to be by default but I have found how to effectively achieve non-hyphenation by default. I cannot speak for earlier versions of Photoshop - I don't know when these setting were added, but this works in the latest Photoshop CC, at the time of writing.

If you drop down the menu from the paragraph palette, you should see hyphenation on the list. Click it to open options. In the options, put the value of 25 (the maximum setting) the "words longer than" field.

Of course it will still hyphenate words - but only 5 words that I have found in the English language - which you just may want to still hyphenate anyway! LOL

Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis (45 letters)
Pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism (30 letters)
Floccinaucinihilipilification (29 letters)
Antidisestablishmentarianism (28 letters)
Thyroparathyroidectomized (25 letters)